# Logic for physics

Tags: logic, reference-request, mathematical-physics, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

I'm looking for references on applications of logic (e.g. intuitionistic logic, toposes) to physics (especially quantum physics, as this is the area that I'm aware can be helped by logical considerations, but I'm open to other areas as well).

My motivation is that I read/heard multiple times that quantum physics could be well apprehended through, say, topos theory (I've heard the following sentence, which was probably an exageration : "The laws of quantum physics are the same laws as those of classical physics, but interpreted in a different topos"); but also I know that there's a thing called quantum logic even though I don't know much about it.

The references could be either technical ones (but if possible self-contained, or at least not requiring too much bagage in physics) or sort of vulgarized, not too technical ones (though I would want a bit more than "oh it can be applied, and it's interesting"), I don't really mind.

Comment: Not certain, but I understand the quantum logic isn't used much by physicists these days. It looks like classical logic reigns supreme in physics as in most other fields.

Comment: @DanChristensen : yes surely classical logic reigns supreme but other logics could have some interesting insights/applications

Comment: Are there any proofs obtained using these other logics that could not be obtained through more conventional means with a bit of effort? It seems that proofs in all formal logics can be verified using ordinary digital computers (turing machines?) which themselves are based on classical logic. Just a hunch, but perhaps there is something universal about classical logic.

Comment: @DanChristensen : well no, that's the point of different logics. If they were all equivalent to classical logic, we wouldn't study them. (There's nothing universal about classical logic)

Comment: Intuitionism seems to be just classical logic with half the rules disabled. You might be able to "code" modal logic using 3 or more symbols for truth-values with suitable assumptions expressed in FOL.

Comment: @DanChristensen not half the rules, just one. But removing a rule allows you to add axioms that would otherwise be contradictory. I *know* for a fact that some people are envisioning topos theory for instance as a way of making sense of quantum physics, so if you're just going to say "classical logic is enough", it's really not going to be useful for my question

Comment: It seems to me that there are several useful methods of proof that are banned by intuitionist logic, e.g. many existence proofs, proof by contradiction, proof by contrapositive, some properties of material implication, proof by cases.  And I'm guessing that formal proofs in topos theory can be verified by suitable software on an ordinary digital computer using classical logic. That suggests to me that topos theory can be looked as a theorem of classical logical with the required assumptions being introduced in classical logic (FOL).

Comment: @DanChristensen : They're all reducible to the law of excluded middle. And yes perhaps they can, but again, that's *not the point*

Comment: @Max There are tons of references to this kind of thing on nLab e.g. [the Bohr Topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bohr+topos), [the Geometry of Physics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometry+of+physics), and [various works by Urs Schreiber](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Urs+Schreiber#myresearch). A lot of these are fairly technical, geared more at addressing issues in quantum field theory. More generally are ideas related to [cohesion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motivation+for+cohesive+toposes). Also what's produced is usually an intuitionistic type theory, not just a logic.

Comment: @Dan: You are quite right in that we can formalize almost all results about provability in very weak systems such as PRA ("Turing machines with the ability of general recursion taken away and only primitive recursion left"). That is, while PRA cannot verify most mathematical facts, it sure can verify that more advanced systems such as Peano arithmetic, ZFC or various type systems verify those facts. In this sense, systems which go beyond PRA are not needed. (Note that coincidentally, PRA is so weak that removing the law of excluded middle from it yields an equivalent system.) However, ...

Comment: @Dan: ... strong intuitionistic systems are still extremely valuable, because it turns out that there is a host of structures which validate intuitionistic logic (but not classical logic, irrespective of one's philosophical commitments). Examples for these structures are toposes of sheaves over non-discrete topological spaces. [Here is a short set of slides surveying applications of this insight.](https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/slides-leipzig2018.pdf) Max: I second all of Derek's suggestions.